# Data pre-processing for sklearn's SVM without using the train_test_split method

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, svm

I used Inception and generated 1000 features (probabilities of objects) for about ~11000 videos. These videos have already been categorized by genre and I want the SVM to predict which genre a video belongs to.

I want to apply SVM to these feature vectors but every tutorial I've read so far has used the `train_test_split` method from `sklearn.model_selection`.

How my data looks:

- I have separated my dataset into two csv files with ~9000 training and ~2000 testing (each with 1000 features) records. It's in the format of `videoId,feature1,feature2,...,feature1000`
- I have files with genres as titles e.g. `Training/education.txt` for training and `Testing/education.txt` for testing. Each file contains `videoId`s that belong to said genre.

I'm new to data science and libraries like pandas, sklearn, etc. so I'm lost on how I should prepare this data. I've been following [this guide](https://stackabuse.com/implementing-svm-and-kernel-svm-with-pythons-scikit-learn):

```py
import pandas as pd  

bankdata = pd.read_csv("D:/Datasets/bill_authentication.csv")  
X = bankdata.drop('Class', axis=1)  
y = bankdata['Class']  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)
```

How would I go about getting `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test` with what I've got? I can't use methods like `train_test_split` because of how my data is set up at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that all the tutorials advise you to use `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model.selection` is because they assume you will want to evaluate the performance of your learning model, and possibly tweak its hyperparameters before you finally use it to generate predictions on your test dataset.

This practice is known as setting aside a "cross-validation" set. To do this, you leave your test set untouched for the time being, and actually split off around 20% of the rows of your training set. You train your model on 80% of your training set's rows, and use that model to generate predictions on that remaining 20% of your training set.

You can choose a metric, such as [accuracy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html), to judge the performance of your model. Oftentimes, it's at this point that you will want to experiment with trying out different values for the [hyperparameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) of your model, and see whether or not its score on the validation set (that last 20% of the training set) improves.

The `train_test_split` method is just a simple way to split up your training data into these 80/20 portions. I recommend that you don't skip this step. The reason is that if you were to change your model or its hyperparameters after observing how well it performs on your *actual test set*, you will lose any basis for knowing how your model would perform on brand new, real-world data.

This is called "overfitting to the test set" and it's a common error of practice that leads to machine learning models that perform really well on a set of previously-collected data, and yet (to the surprise of their creators) ultimately perform quite horribly on the real data that these models see when they're finally put into production.

To sum things up, the idea is that you:

1. Train on 80% of your train data.
2. Evaluate on 20% of your train data.
3. Change your model until your satisfied with how it scores on the data used in step (2.).
4. Finally, only at the end, use your model to make predictions on your actual test data.

Incidentally, Sklearn's naming of the method `train_test_split` is somewhat confusing because the purpose of the method is the creation of a validation set. (`train_val_split` would seem to me to be a more intuitive name...)

Here are the steps, in code, I imagine you'd want to follow given your particular situation (data split across several .txt files):

1. Imports modules and all your training .csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_edu = pd.read_csv('Training/education.txt')
X_hor = pd.read_csv('Training/horror.txt')
...
```

2. Create a `Genre` column in each genre's dataframe and then concatenate all these into one dataframe:

```
train_dfs = [X_edu, X_hor, ...]
genres = ['edu', 'hor', ...]
for i, genre in enumerate(genres):
    train_dfs[i]['Genre'] = genre

X = pd.concat[train_dfs].reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index so each row has a unique index
                                                # important so we can be sure we can properly match each row with its label
```

3. Extract the labels from the training data (I'm assuming the labels are in a column titled `Genre` or something similar) and drop `videoID` column (since it doesn't appear that it's a predictive feature):

```
y = X['Genre']
X = X.drop(['Genre', 'videoID'], axis=1)
```

4. Use `train_test_split` to create your training and validation sets (nice bonus: `train_test_split` automatically shuffles the rows of your entire training dataframe before splitting it, so you won't have to worry about some genres not being in your validation set):

```
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)
```

5. Fit your model to `X_train` and make predictions on `X_val`:

```
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
preds = clf.predict(X_val)
```

6. Ascertain your model's performance on these predictions made on the validation set (I use accuracy here, but you can use whichever metric you want -- Sklearn likely has a class for any metric you'd wanna use.)

```
val_acc = accuracy_score(y_val, preds)
```

7. Experiment with different values for your SVM learner's [hyperparameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) and repeat steps (5.) and (6.) above. When you're satisfied with your model's performance, now's the time to go and generate predictions on your actual test data.

   You can load in your test .csv files for each genre and assemble them all together into one dataframe just like you did for your training data above:

```
test_edu = pd.read_csv('Training/education.txt')
test_hor = pd.read_csv('Training/horror.txt')
...

test_dfs = [test_edu, test_hor, ...]
for i, genre in enumerate(genres):
    test_dfs[i]['Genre'] = genre

test = pd.concat[test_dfs].reset_index(drop=True) # reset the index so each row has a unique index
y_test = test['Genre']
X_test = test.drop(['Genre', 'videoID'], axis=1)
test_preds = clf.predict(X_test)
test_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, test_preds)
```

And this test set accuracy score should give your the most realistic estimate possible of how your model would fare should it be asked to make a prediction on a brand new video it has never seen before.